# Which form of chromium oxide is formed naturally in the atmosphere?

Tags: stoichiometry

I'm trying to figure out which form of chromium oxide forms naturally in our atmosphere, i.e., if you take a piece of elemental $\ce{Cr}$ from vacuum to a normal, room temperature environment with air, does it form $\ce{CrO}$ on the surface? Or $\ce{Cr2O3}$? Etc.

[This site](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Inorganic_Chemistry/Descriptive_Chemistry/d-Block_Elements/Group_6%3A_Transition_Metals/Chemistry_of_Chromium#Chromium_Oxides_and_Hydroxides) says:

> Chromium (III) oxide, $\ce{Cr2O3}$ is the main oxide of chromium.

So it seems like it might be that one, but "main" is pretty vague. Does anyone have a more definitive answer, with a source?

thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An investigation of the phase diagram reveals that the only stable chrome oxide near room temperature is $\ce{Cr2O3}$.  $\ce{Cr3O4}$ appears, but only near 2000K.  There is no stable chrome analogue to $\ce{FeO}$ on the phase diagram.

Thus, the one stable oxide that will form under normal atmospheric conditions is $\ce{Cr2O3}$. However, note that it is easy to find mixed metal-oxygen compounds with high mutual solubility.

If you are interested in the thermodynamics of the $\ce{Cr-O}$ system, you could start with [M. Kowalski and P.J. Spencer, Calphad *19(3) 229-243* (**1995**)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0364591695000249), which covers the $\ce{Cr-O, Fe-O}$ and $\ce{Ni-O}$ systems

Comment: Thanks! That paper was actually perfect because I had the same question about Nickel Oxide!

Comment: Quite welcome! If your institution has access, the ASM Alloy Phase Diagram Database at asminternational.org is a great place to start looking for info. Thermodynamic information can be found in various journals including Calphad, J. Alloys and Compounds, Intermetallics, amd Met. Trans A.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing a parallel to the formation of rust (oxides of iron), in which the following [reactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust):
$$\ce{Fe<=>Fe^2+ +2e-}$$
$$\ce{4Fe^2+ +O2<=>4Fe^3+ +2O^2-}$$
form both of the oxidation states of iron, reacting to eventually form both $\ce{Fe2O3}$ and $\ce{FeO}$, the two most common forms of rust. The [more common](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_oxide) of the two forms is $\ce{Fe2O3}$, which is likely because $\ce{Fe^3+}$ has an electron configuration of $[\ce{Ar}] 3d^5$, which is more stable than the electron configuration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$, which is $[\ce{Ar}] 3d^6$.

It is likely then that both $\ce{CrO}$ and $\ce{Cr2O3}$ form when $\ce{Cr}$ is exposed to the atmosphere, and also that $\ce{Cr^3+}$ has a more stable electron configuration than $\ce{Cr^2+}$, though this is not intuitive since neither half an empty or half-filled 3d orbital.

Comment: I am not sure about CrO forming under normal atmospheric conditions. If it did, it would likely be the predominant oxidation product (similar to FeO predominating when iron is oxidized at high temperature). Passivation (therefore "stainless" in stainless steel) would be much less effective with Cr. In reality Cr(II) seems to exist primarily as a solution species at high temperature.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [by Jon Custer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/28448/17175), only chromium(III) oxide is thermodynamically stable as a pure chromium oxide and only that oxide is normally formed on chromium in our atmosphere. However, chomium(II) oxide may exist as a component in solid solution with other metal(II) oxides. [Gasik[1]](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-097753-9.00008-3) gives a phase diagram for chromium oxide in magnesium oxide at high temperature under an oxygen fugacity equal to that of air (0.2 atmosphere). The $\ce{CrO}$ component is soluble in magnesia up to about 16 weight percent $\ce{CrO}$ at 1500°C, with the solubility increasing at higher temperature. Adding chromium above the solubility limit, or cooling a given composition so that the chromium(II) solubility drops, results in formation of the spinel phase $\ce{MgCr^{III}_2O4}$. Since magnesia is plentiful in Earth's mantle, chromium delivered there may take the form of this chromium(II) solution species, releasing oxygen or oxidizing other elements (such as iron) as it is reduced from chromium(III).

[image]

[Eechout et al[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5QfQ.jpg)](https://doi.org/10.2138/am.2007.2318) studied the oxidation state of chromium in minerals synthesizedunder physical n chemical conditions simulating the lower mantle; they also report that chromjum(III) used in the starting material reduces to chromium(II) and thus, in oxide minerals to the $\ce{CrO}$ component:

> $\ce{Cr}$ K-edge X-ray absorption near-edge structure (XANES) spectra were recorded on $\ce{Cr:MgO}$ periclase and $\ce{Cr:(Mg,Fe)O}$ ferropericlase synthesized at different pressures (4 and 12 GPa) and temperatures (1200 to 1400 °C) at reducing oxygen fugacity conditions (~iron-wüstite buffer IW to IW - 2), and on $\ce{Cr:MgSiO3}$ perovskite with 0.5 wt% $\ce{Cr2O3}$... In $\ce{Cr:(Mg,Fe)O}$ the relative $\ce{Cr^{2+}}$ content reached at most 12.5% but results from Mössbauer spectroscopy combined with chemical composition data suggest that some $\ce{Cr^{2+}}$ oxidized during cooling through the reaction $\ce{Cr^{2+} + Fe^{3+} -> Cr^{3+} + Fe^{2+}}$. In iron-free $\ce{Cr:MgO}$, the $\ce{Cr^{2+}}$ content is much higher and reaches ~40%. In $\ce{Cr:MgSiO3}$ perovskite with 0.006 $\ce{Cr}$ pfu (similar to estimated lower mantle abundance), chromium is mainly divalent.

**References**

1. Mihail I. Gasik, "Chapter 8 - Technology of Chromium and Its Ferroalloys",
   Editor(s): Michael Gasik,
   *Handbook of Ferroalloys,
   Butterworth-Heinemann*, 2013,
   Pages 267-316,
   ISBN 9780080977539,
   https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-097753-9.00008-3.
2. Eeckhout, Sigrid Griet; Bolfan-Casanova, Nathalie; Mccammon, Catherine; Klemme, Stephan; and Amiguet, Elodie. "XANES study of the oxidation state of Cr in lower mantle phases: Periclase and magnesium silicate perovskite" *American Mineralogist*, **92**(5-6), 2007, pp. 966-972. https://doi.org/10.2138/am.2007.2318